# Conditional recode and sum in R

Tags: r, data-manipulation, recode

My (sample) data look as follows:

```
mydata <- structure(list(x1 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), x2 = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 4L), x3 = c(1L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 
1L, 5L, 6L, 6L), week = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 30L, 50L, 
22L, 52L, 36L, 25L, 26L), newar1 = c(0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L), newvar2 = c(0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 
2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("x1", "x2", 
"x3", "week", "newar1", "newvar2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-14L))



x1  x2  x3  week
0   1   1   0
0   2   3   0
0   3   5   0
0   1   1   0
0   2   3   0
0   3   5   0
1   1   1   1
1   2   4   30
1   3   5   50
1   1   2   22
1   2   1   52
1   3   5   36
1   4   6   25
1   4   6   26
```

I would like to create 1 new variable `newvar1`:

- if x1 = 0 => I would like to count the number of times in the entire dataset where x1 equals 1 (only other rows, excluding the own observation), but only count rows with the same combination of x2 and x3 and rows where the week number is larger than 24.
- if x1 = 1 => I would like to count the number of times in the entire dataset where x1 equals 1, but only count rows with the same combination of x2 and x3 and rows where the week number minus 25 is larger than zero ((week-25)>0)).

By "sum" I mean the number of times x1 equals 1 if the conditions hold.

By "if" I mean I only want to sum x1 when the conditions following the if hold. Basically my question is: how can I only sum certain values based on conditions?

My data should look like:

```
x1  x2  x3  week newvar1
0   1   1   0    0       
0   2   3   0    0       
0   3   5   0    2       
0   1   1   0    0       
0   2   3   0    0       
0   3   5   0    2       
1   1   1   1    0       
1   2   4   30   0       
1   3   5   50   1       
1   1   2   22   0       
1   2   1   52   0       
1   3   5   36   0       
1   4   6   25   0       
1   4   6   26   1
```

Currently I have the following code, but this does not take into account the constraints for `x2=x3` and for week. Any suggestions how to do this?

```
mydata[,newvar1:=sum(x1), by=list(x2,x3)]
```

Comment: Please use dput() to provide a reproducible example

Comment: Included, thank you.

Comment: I'm having a lot of trouble understanding the criteria for `newvar1` and `newvar2`.

Comment: Could you clarify the logic needed for the creation of `newvar1` and `newvar2`? For example, why does `newvar2 = 2` in the second row?

Comment: Agreed this was not clear! I simplified and clarified it, basically my question  is how I can only sum certain values based on multiple conditions?

Comment: Criteria are still unclear. What do you mean by "sum(x1)"?

Comment: I would like to get the sum of all 1's of x1, or, otherwise stated, the number of times it equals 1

Comment: I'm really confused. The third row, `x1` is 0. `x2` is 3. `x3` is 5. `week` is 0. Your `newvar` result is `2`. I can't figure out why. Here are my guesses: You code makes it sound like for this row of `newvar` you want to sum `x1` for all rows where the `x2` and `x3` values match *on that row* (`x2 == x3`) AND the week is more than 24. Because `x2` and `x3` are always different on a single row, this will always be 0.

Comment: My next guess is that what you *mean* is that you want to sum `x1` for all rows where `x3` is equal to *this value* of `x2`. You could code this as `x3 == x2[3]` (since we're on the 3rd row) AND week > 24. There are 2 rows where `x3` is 3, but both have low week numbers and `0` values for `x1`, so this can't be right.

Comment: My third guess was that I had it switched - that you want to sum all rows where the `x2` value matches the current row's `x3` value, but there aren't any of those (`x3[3]` is 5 and `x2` is never 5), so that's wrong as well. So I'm stumped. Can you explain, in words how you arrive at the result of `2` for the third row?

Comment: I adapted the post. I would like to count the number of times/rows in the entire dataset where x1 equals 1, but only count rows that have the same combination of x2 and x3 and rows and where the week number is larger than 24.

Comment: Okay, this is better. I've got code that matches all the cases when `x1` is 0. Now, what about row 9? `x1` is 1, `x2` is 3, `x3` is 5, week is `50`. We should be counting rows where `x1` is 1, `x2` and `x3` match (are 3 and 5), and `week - 25 > 0`, (which is equivalent to `week > 25`). It looks like Row 9 itself fits the conditions and also Row 12 - so the answer should be 2. Bur your answer is 0. Why?

Comment: You are right. I adapted. Sorry for all the confusion.

Comment: You adapted to 1 - to me it still looks like it should be 2. In fact, rows 8, 9, 11-14 all match themselves. Do you want to only count *other* rows?

Comment: Correct, only other rows

Comment: @research111 then shouldn't row 14 be 0 while row 13 is 1? why isn't row 12 equal to 1?

Answer (score 0):

I think we can use a `for` loop to get this done:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(mydata)){
 if(mydata[i,1] == 0){ # x1 == 0
   mydata[i,]$newvar1 = 
    sum(mydata[-i,1] == 1 & # count where x1 == 1
        mydata[i,2] == mydata[-i,2] & # and where (x2 == x2) & (x3 == x3)
        mydata[i,3] == mydata[-i,3] & 
        mydata[-i,4] > 24) # and week > 24
 }else{ # x1 == 1
    mydata[i,]$newvar1 = 
        sum(mydata[-i,1] == 1 & # count where x1 == 1
            mydata[i,2] == mydata[-i,2] & # and where (x2 == x2) & (x3 == x3)
            mydata[i,3] == mydata[-i,3] & 
            mydata[-i,4] > 25) # and week > 25
    }
}

# mydata
#    x1 x2 x3 week newvar1
# 1   0  1  1    0       0
# 2   0  2  3    0       0
# 3   0  3  5    0       2
# 4   0  1  1    0       0
# 5   0  2  3    0       0
# 6   0  3  5    0       2
# 7   1  1  1    1       0
# 8   1  2  4   30       0
# 9   1  3  5   50       1
# 10  1  1  2   22       0
# 11  1  2  1   52       0
# 12  1  3  5   36       1
# 13  1  4  6   25       1
# 14  1  4  6   26       0
```

Alternatively, if, for `x1 == 1` you want to compare data on *all* rows:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(mydata)){
    if(mydata[i,1] == 0){ # x1 == 0
        mydata[i,]$newvar1 = 
            sum(mydata[-i,1] == 1 & #count where x1 = 1
                    mydata[i,2] == mydata[-i,2] & # and where (x2 == x2) & (x3 == x3)
                    mydata[i,3] == mydata[-i,3] & 
                    mydata[-i,4] > 24) # and week > 24
    }else{
        mydata[i,]$newvar1 = 
            sum(mydata[,1] == 1 &
                mydata[i,2] == mydata[,2] & 
                mydata[i,3] == mydata[,3] & 
                mydata[,4] > 25)
    }
}

# mydata
#    x1 x2 x3 week newvar1
# 1   0  1  1    0       0
# 2   0  2  3    0       0
# 3   0  3  5    0       2
# 4   0  1  1    0       0
# 5   0  2  3    0       0
# 6   0  3  5    0       2
# 7   1  1  1    1       0
# 8   1  2  4   30       1
# 9   1  3  5   50       2
# 10  1  1  2   22       0
# 11  1  2  1   52       1
# 12  1  3  5   36       2
# 13  1  4  6   25       1
# 14  1  4  6   26       1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mydata$newvar1 <- ifelse(mydata$x1==0, sapply(seq_len(nrow(mydata)), function(i) with (mydata, sum(x1[week > 25 & x2==x2[i] & x3==x3[i]]))), 0)
mydata$newvar1 <- ifelse(mydata$x1==1, sapply(seq_len(nrow(mydata)), function(i) with (mydata, sum(x1[week < week[i] & week[i]!=0 & week-week[i]<25 & x2==x2[i] & x3==x3[i]]))), mydata$newvar1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
mydata %>% group_by(x2, x3) %>%
    mutate(newvar1 = ifelse(x1 == 0,
                            sum(x1 * week > 24),
                            sum(x1 * week > 25) - (week > 25) * (x1 == 1)))
# Source: local data frame [14 x 6]
# Groups: x2, x3 [7]
# 
#       x1    x2    x3  week newvar2 newvar1
#    <int> <int> <int> <int>   <int>   <int>
# 1      0     1     1     0       0       0
# 2      0     2     3     0       2       0
# 3      0     3     5     0       0       2
# 4      0     1     1     0       0       0
# 5      0     2     3     0       2       0
# 6      0     3     5     0       0       2
# 7      1     1     1     1       0       0
# 8      1     2     4    30       0       0
# 9      1     3     5    50       1       1
# 10     1     1     2    22       0       0
# 11     1     2     1    52       0       0
# 12     1     3     5    36       0       1
# 13     1     4     6    25       0       1
# 14     1     4     6    26       0       0
```

The weird bit in the `else` condition, `- (week > 25) * (x1 == 1)`, is to subtract 1 from rows that would otherwise match themselves.